# Only describing postgres tables with "\d" (not sequences, indexes, views, ...)

Tags: postgresql

I want to describe every table in a postgres database.

Currently I have this:

```
psql -d db -c "\d *" > db_description.txt
```

But this also includes all sequences, views, etc.

Is there a command where the `*` pattern only matches tables?
Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about simply using the `\dt` command? It's here to list tables only. You can get more help on PostgreSQL inner commands by issuing the `\?` command.

If you want to know what those commands do behind the scenes, you could also start psql with the -E option, as [asked here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131028/get-equivalent-sql-query-for-any-postgres-meta-command). You could therefore rewrite this query to get exactly what you want, be it views, sequences, tables... or any combination of the above.

Answer (score 1):

You can massage the output of that until you strip everything you don't want:

```
psql -d db -c '\d *' |\
  sed -n '/^ *Table/,/^\([^T -]\|$\)/p' |\
  grep -v '^\([^T ]\|Tablesp\| *Col\|$\)' |\
  sed 's/^ *Table "\([^"]*\)"/\n\1:/'
```

Answer (score 0):

## *Describe* ONLY Tables Using *awk* Filter

I will iteratively demonstrate how to do this from within the PostgreSQL interactive terminal (psql). It can be adapted to run as a shell command using the `-c` option.

1. Pipe output—of the next command—to an awk filter to print only
   table definitions.

   ```
   pachl=# \o |awk '/^ *Table "/, /^$/'
   ```

   This awk command prints all lines between start/stop pairs
   (e.g. `/start/, /stop/`). This filter expression is fairly simple because
   PostgreSQL delimits each object with a common header
   (e.g. Table "schema.entity") and an empty line.

   *Or*, if you want definitions to go directly into a file for later
   reference, you can instead do:

   ```
   pachl=# \o |awk '/^ *Table "/, /^$/' >/tmp/tbldef
   ```
2. Describe **all** tables, views, sequences, and indices in a schema.

   ```
   pachl=# \d YOUR-SCHEMA.*
   ```

   The awk filter will only print table definitions. Specifying a schema name is
   probably what you want. Without a qualifying schema the wildcard (`*`)
   will include PostgreSQL catalog objects, public, etc.
3. Reset output when finished.

   ```
   pachl=# \o
   ```

   This will remove the awk filter pipe.

### *Describe* ONLY Indices, Sequences, or Views

This awk filter can modified to describe other types of objects too.

- **Indices**

  ```
  pachl=# \o |awk '/^ *Index "/, /^$/'
  ```
- **Sequences**

  ```
  pachl=# \o |awk '/^ *Sequence "/, /^$/'
  ```
- **Views**

  ```
  pachl=# \o |awk '/^ *View "/, /^$/'
  ```